# How to get customer id using object manager in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, object-manager

How to get customer id using object manager?

Comment: please confirm do u want using by email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **Objectmanager is not  a standard way** but still if you want to get using object manager then 
**First load customer session object and than load customer data**

Try below code :

```
   $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
    $customerSession = $om->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');  
    $customerData = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getData(); //get all data of customerData
    $customerData = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();//get id of customer
```

Comment: @ShyamHajare if you found this answer as helpful please accept it so other user gets helped

Answer (score 1):

in Your Block class

```
  protected $customer;
  public function __construct(
    .............
     \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customer,
    ............
  ){
       $this->customer = $customer;
  }

  public function yourMethodName(){
    $customer = $this->customer;
    echo $customer->getName(); 
    echo $customer->getId(); //You will get all basic detail with this $customer object
  }
```